# probability, women selected, brewery selected

Tags: permutations

There are $9$ women, who each own $4$ breweries, and $12$ men, who each own $9$ breweries. I pick $4$ people at random (without replacing).

a) Let $Y$ = the total number of breweries. Write down the pmf of $Y$ (probability of each possible number of breweries).

My work on 3a):

The probability to select $k$ shrubberies and $4-k$ shrubberies is: $$\frac{\binom{13}{k}\binom{13}{4-k}}{\binom{13}{4}}$$
*It is the permutation, with first num on top, not sure how to use correct format
**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand the question.  We pick $4$ out of the $21$ people, and count how many breweries they own.  If we happen to pick $4$ men, we get $36$.  If we pick $4$ women, we get $16$.  The probability that all the people we choose are men is $$\frac{\binom{12}4\binom90}{\binom{21}{4}}$$  The denominator is the number of ways to choose $4$ people from the $21$ owners.  The numerator is the number of ways to choose $4$ men and $0$ women.  This is the only way to arrive at $36$ breweries.  Therefore,

$$Y(36)=\frac{\binom{12}4\binom90}{\binom{21}{4}}$$

Can you do the other cases now?

Comment: Take a look at how I edited your post.  If you plan to spend some time here, I recommend you learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  You'll find you get a much better response when your post is easy to read.

Comment: I will start today, thanks